# jquery infinite scroller

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroller

I would like to load content while scrolling with jquery an I found something useful but doesn't work for me:

link: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/

in Firefox i successfully make 5 ajax calls and append content on bottom but then it stops working. what could go wrong?

Code when i call ajax function is bellow:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
       ajax
    }
});
```

is it possible to make ajax calls 100 px before scroller reach bottom?

@Val code on jsfiddle works with its condition:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height()) - $(window).height() - 100){}
```

it is weird that in ff doesn't work with this condition when I reach bottom

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height()) - $(window).height()){}
```

in firefox I make 6 ajax posts with second condition but then it stops working...

Any explanation for that?

Comment: its most likely that you are making toooo many ajax calls in short intervals [period of time], 1 servers can't handle toooo many requests, 2 may be considered as spam and may even block u in some instances, you should disable new ajax requests until the other one has finished, so they are queued up...

Comment: Have you tried just using an interval to check the position of the scroll? As Val points out, you may be sending too many requests. Instead of `scroll` event (which can get fired for little bit of the scroll), try having an interval timer that hits every second/few seconds. If the page meets your scroll criteria, then make a request.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok this, could take a long time, [trying to explain] but hopefully this will help

http://demo.webdeveloperplus.com/dynamic-scrollbox/ 
[thats the demo ]

http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/create-a-dynamic-scrolling-content-box-using-ajax/
[that is the how to]